# airflow 1.10.5 scheduler connection errors to postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, airflow

Airflow 1.10.5
Celery executor

Airflow scheduler crashing with postgres sqlalchemy connection error (details of error below) This error exists in one environment , other similar environment works. Is there any version incompatibilities, appreciate any help to resolve.

To isolate issue, Testing the connections to postgres manually works without issues

**Example connection code (sqlalchemy postgres functioning)**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@servername.postgres.database.azure.com/airflow", echo=True, pool_size=6, max_overflow=10, encoding='latin1')

engine.connect()

print(engine)
```

**Error**

```
Celery Task ID: ('example_dag', 'bash_task', datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 8, 0, 0, tzinfo=<TimezoneInfo [UTC, GMT, +00:00:00, STD]>), 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 106, in fetch_celery_task_state
    res = (celery_task[0], celery_task[1].state)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 473, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 412, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 386, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 53, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 122, in _get_task_meta_for
    session = self.ResultSession()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/__init__.py", line 99, in ResultSession
    **self.engine_options)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 59, in session_factory
    self.prepare_models(engine)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/database/session.py", line 54, in prepare_models
    ResultModelBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4294, in create_all
    ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2045, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2037, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2239, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2279, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1544, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2275, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/kaiser2/airflow_venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: any updates on this issue? Currently seeing it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I did face a similar issue.check your postgres configs to see if the config files are in correct place. Last time i faced a similar error was due to the file misplacement of postgresql config file... its strange that i had hardly seen any errors in the posgresql logs but the connections were failing to the postgresql... and port-forward was working.. but the pods in the cluster were unable to connect to the postgresql.

Comment: Not sure if you still have issue. You start seeing these with large volumes. 1. Setup pgbouncer. 2. Reboot worker process when downturn. 3. Switch to flexible server if you are using azure posgres sql .